# @PropertySource on a spring configuration file

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I am trying to write unit tests using Spring.
All the unit tests use the same spring configuration file, but each one has a different properties file with the same keys but different values to this unique test.

I want to define the properties file at the unit test class, but then it doesn't recognize the properties. The only way is to define it at the Spring configuration class, what means that I must change this configuration file every time I want to run a different test.

My test file:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TesterSpringConfig.class}) 
public class FirstTest
```

My configuration file:

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan("com.testing") 
@PropertySource("classpath:FirstTest.properties")
public class TesterSpringConfig
```

Any ideas?